# how to create list of unique dates from a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have thousands of records with motel visit dates like Table A:

```
  Name                 CheckInDate           CheckOutDate
  Pete                  11/1/2016            11/1/2016
  Mike                  11/1/2016            11/2/2016
  Don                   11/1/2016            11/3/2016
```

Need to create query to generate a temp table with unique entry for every date of guests' visit. Like this:

```
 Name                        VisitDate
 Pete                        11/1/2016
 Mike                        11/1/2016
 Mike                        11/2/2016
 Don                         11/1/2016
 Don                         11/2/2016
 Don                         11/3/2016
```

This one has me stumped. I appreciate your help so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tally/calendar table would be optimal, but you can do this via an ad-hoc tally table in concert with a CROSS APPLY like so:

**Example**

```
Select A.[Name] 
      ,VisitDate = B.D
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top (DateDiff(DD,[CheckInDate],[CheckOutDate])+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),[CheckInDate]) 
                 From  master..spt_values n1
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Name    VisitDate
Pete    2016-11-01
Mike    2016-11-01
Mike    2016-11-02
Don     2016-11-01
Don     2016-11-02
Don     2016-11-03
```

> **Edit - If you have (or want) a DateTable**

```
Select A.[Name] 
      ,VistiDate = B.[Date]
 From  YourTable A
 Join  YourDateTable B
  on   B.[Date] between A.[CheckInDate] and A.[CheckOutDate]
```

Comment: Hi John. This is awesome.  From your example, I changed "your table" to first source table from example I gave.   I also left  "master..spt_values"  as -is.    It starts to produce results, than immediately switches to  error "A TOP or FETCH clause contains an invalid value."  Any thoughts?

Comment: @inefficientmkts I suspect a data issue.  NULLS in CheckIn or CheckOut ?  CheckOut less than CheckIn?

Comment: @inefficientmkts Yup, you got NULLs.  By forcing a null value, I was able to create your error.

Comment: Now it works great!!  I can't thank you enough!!!  Seriously.....made my day.  I will learn more about cross apply. That's new territory for me.

Comment: @inefficientmkts Happy it helped.  ... In only takes ONE  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use just union

```
select name, checkindate as visitdate from guests
 union
select name, checkoutdate as vistidate from guests
```

Union will take care of distinct as well

Comment: As I understand, OP wants all days list from `CheckInDate` to            `CheckOutDate` for each visitor

Comment: oh gotcha... that i did'nt noticed